# Calculate image height & width in fast way

Tags: php, image

I have following program to calculate image height and width in fast manner as compare getImageSize(); PHP function. The reason? Remote image will need to be downloaded into your server and then it will be read locally by php.

```
<?php
   function getimagesize($image_url){
    $handle = fopen ($image_url, "rb");
    $contents = ""; 
            if ($handle) {
                do {
                    $count += 1;
                    $data = fread($handle, 8192);
                        if (strlen($data) == 0) {
                            break;
                       }   
                $contents .= $data;
                } while(true);
            } else { return false; }
    fclose ($handle);

    $im = ImageCreateFromString($contents);
    if (!$im) { return false; }
    $gis[0] = ImageSX($im);
    $gis[1] = ImageSY($im);
    // array member 3 is used below to keep with current getimagesize standards
    $gis[3] = "width={$gis[0]} height={$gis[1]}";
    ImageDestroy($im);
    return $gis;                                                                                                                                                       
   }   
$image_url = "http://xample.com/4.jpg";
$get = getimagesize($image_url);
print $get;

?>
```

But after executing this php code i am getting following error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getimagesize() in C:\wamp\www\test\CheckWH.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a standard-method called getImageSize in PHP. Rename your method and everything's fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use standard method getimagesize() from php

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("http://xample.com/4.jpg"); 
echo "$width x $height (px)";
```

Comment: please read question , i have given reason why i can not use getimagesize.